# RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in scalar negative

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting this warning when I upgrade my numpy from `1.23.3` to `1.25.0`

```
#For 1.23.3 version

import numpy as np
x = np.uint64(0xffffffff)

print(-x)
#output
18446744069414584321
```

---

```
#For 1.25.0 version

import numpy as np
x = np.uint64(0xffffffff)

print(-x)
#output
18446744069414584321
<ipython-input-4-adbfb5bb01c0>:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in scalar negative
  print(-x)
```

Anyone else is getting this warning message or its just me?

Comment: What does `-x` mean for an unsigned integer?

Comment: No, actually.  You can't negate an unsigned number.  You can convert it to signed, then negate, then convert back to unsigned.  You seem to expect this to happen automatically, but that's a dangerous operation, and I think you're being warned of that.

Comment: Oh.. I see but, we don't have warning in `1.23` version? Also, I think in other languages like C++/C people do this?

Comment: The C standards dictate that an unsigned value gets converted to a signed value to participate in expressions like this.  I'm just cautioning that there is no universal agreement on what that expression means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a bug reported at numpy/issues which is very similar to my question:

Here is the link:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/24737

They are planning to make the changes in `numpy 1.26.2`